# integration by parts/ improper integral question

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, improper-integrals

This is from an old qualifying examination question.

Let $a>1$ be fixed. Show that

$$ \displaystyle A_N=\pi i a \int_1^N t^{a-\frac{3}{2}}e^{\pi i t^a} dt $$

converges to some complex number as $N \rightarrow \infty$.

I tried using integration by parts, but no luck. Is there something that 
I'm missing here?. Any hints and comments are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I can barely see it but what is $s$?

Comment: @julien: the term inside the integral is exp ^ {pi i t^a}.
There is no s anywhere.

Comment: On my screen, there is also $t^{\alpha-s/2}$. But I can not either write @user54755 at the beginning of my comment. I might need a new computer.

Comment: @julien: Sorry about that inside the integral there is
t^{a-3/2} times what I wrte before. I wrote that in \LaTeX code I see no reason why it does not show properly. Thanks for looking though.

Comment: Ah! Ok. I swear this $3$ really looks like an $s$ on y screen. Sorry.

Comment: @julien: The ping at the beginning of your comment was automatically removed because there was no-one else to whom your comment could have been directed. Now that I've commented, this should no longer happen. Regarding the $s$ or $3$, note that you can either follow the edit link or select "Show Math As:TeX Commands" in the context menu (right-click on the formula) to see the raw input, in which the $s$ and the $3$ are more easily distinguishable.

Comment: @joriki Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user54755: Since integration by parts should work, you might want to show your attempt at using it so the answer could point out where you went wrong.

Comment: Well I have:

$$A_N=N^{-1/2}e^{\pi i N^a}+1+\frac{1}{2}\left[\int_1^N \frac{e^{\pi i t^a}}{t^{3/2}} \right] $$

I don't see why the last integral has to converge.? In fact it looks as if the first term is not going to zero or some finite number as $N\rightarrow \infty$ either?.

Comment: @user54755: I got exactly that.  Maybe you should move your result to the answer section and expand it a little.

Comment: @rlgordonma: Thanks for your answer. I've got it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like an integration by parts should do the job, though.

Setting $u=t^{-1/2}$ and $dv=t^{a-1}e^{i\pi t^a}dt$, you get:
$$
A_N= N^{-1/2}e^{i\pi N^a} +1  + \int_1^N \frac{1}{2} t^{-3/2}e^{i\pi t^a}dt.
$$
Now it is clear that this converges to
$$
1+\int_1^{+\infty} \frac{1}{2} t^{-3/2}e^{i\pi t^a}dt.
$$
In particular, note that the last integral converges absolutely since $3/2>1$.

Edit: I have just seen your last comment. For the first term, we have $|N^{-1/2}e^{i\pi N^a}|=1/\sqrt{N}\rightarrow 0$ as $N\rightarrow+\infty$.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. I see what went wrong now. I totally forgot that $e^{i\pi}$ terms are unimodular and therefore the integral converges.

Comment: @user54755 You're most welcome. Plus you had already got the good idea.